# QlikView script fetching only first record

Tags: neo4j, cypher, qlikview

I am using `JDBC Connector` for connecting `QlikView` to the `Neo4J Graph Database`.

But the problem I am having is that when I am writing the Cypher Queries, Its fetching only first node. And when I am using same Neo4J JDBC Connector and fetching through Java Its fetching all the records which it should ? Do i have to apply any loop or something in Script to fetch more data in QlikView.

```
   SQL START a=node(*) Return a;
```

The above query is fetching only one row in the `QlikView` and 1000 approx rows Through `Java` code and `Neo4j` Console.
Is there any other way to fetch the record from Neo4J why is it giving different results ?

Even when I am using .qvw file of [this](http://tiqview.tumblr.com/post/24953750981/working-with-graph-data-from-neo4j-in-qlikview) example its not giving me any data ?

Can anybody guide me that what I am doing wrong with this ? Why I am getting different(Always single record) results in `QlikView`

Thank You.

Comment: Which JDBC connector is that? Have your tried the JDBC connector from TIQView http://www.tiq-solutions.de/display/loesungen/JDBC

Comment: @seebach Yes. I am using the same JDBC connector

Comment: I've pinged the developer, I hope he will answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need column aliases like here:

```
SQL START n=node(*) 
RETURN ID(n) as NodeID, n as NodeText, n.__type__ as NodeType, n.name as NodeName, ...
```